# How do use the if symbol in a before_save callback?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  before_save :normalize_card_number, if: :paid_with_card?
end
```

Does the above code mean that before saving an object we call the normalize_card_number only if paid_with_card method has been called?

Comment: Why? Is it not working the way you describe it?

Answer (score 4):

No. This actually mean that the `normalize_card_number` method will be called only if the `paid_with_card?` methods returns true.

For a quick reference, there's an excellent guide about this:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#conditional-callbacks

Comment: Kudos. Nicely put!

Comment: Ironically, thats where i got it from. I just didnt understand what the ? meant. Thanks for clearing that up

Comment: @cLMaine It's a common Ruby idiom to have 'predicate methods', or methods that return `true` or `false`, end with `?` e.g. `is_a?`, `nil?`, `zero?`